# Simple ftp downloader / http proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For a project i'm working on I need to provide http access to files that i only have ftp access to. This is used be an external service that needs to download the files but only supports http. I tried this code below: but CPU/Memory usage is through the roof and it slowly dies. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class ftpproxy : IHttpHandler
{
    // ftpproxy.ashx?src=ftp://username:password@server.com/staticfiles/foo.f4v
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string src = context.Request.QueryString["src"];
        using (Stream instr = wc.OpenRead(src))
        {
            instr.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Oh, and these are large files (hundreds of megs to a couple gigs)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `WebClient` in a using block as well?

Comment: Also, the way your code currently works I believe it's going to load it all into memory, and then write from memory to the disk. If you want to reduce the memory load you'll need to occasionally write to disk.

Comment: I was hoping there was some way to copy straight from the input stream, to the output stream using the 4K buffer that `CopyTo` uses by default, apparently i'm mistaken about how that works?

Comment: I did not wrap the WebClient in a using, but there are only about 15 requests so I don't think that has had much of an impact

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use DownloadFile method from the WebClient end WriteFile from the Response.

```
string src = context.Request.QueryString["src"];
var file = "X:\TEMP\TempFile...";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(src, file);

Context.Response.WriteFile(file);

//Write code to clean File;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't want to stream it to a file then to the response because there are many large files and it would choke the web server's storage during the process (up to 100gb at a time). I was hoping to stream it to the output stream, freeing memory as i go.

Comment: So instead you want to use the server memory? Sorry but I don't know any other way to stream the download directly to the context response.